# Crossbrowser Upload progress meter (without SWFUpload please)

Tags: file-upload

Im trying to make a upload progress meter that works on ALL modern browsers in all operative systems (hence that I don't want to use SWFUpload, since all the demo pages fail in my computer, since I use Ubuntu).

Could someone give me please a hint where to look? I've googled the internet up and down without a solution...

Im running a server with PHP, but APC didnt work, apparently doesnt play nice with lightppd. Also I don't know Perl, so I'd rather not having to learn it for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using ASP.NET not long ago. Basically, there's no pure HTML way to do it. What needs to be done, is to make changes on your server (in ASP.NET, I wrote an HttpModule to cache the current status of the upload - for PHP, Ruby, etc, there's likely similar methods to plug into).

Then on the client side - when a file was being uploaded, I made periodic ajax calls to the server to access the upload data that the server was caching. Then, using javascript, I would update whatever HTML progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

You can see plUpload : http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: That's too intrusive in the design of my page :(

Comment: @Dbugger: You can use a design more simple. See the custom design demo : http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php

Comment: I dont see when I can set the method to "POST" with this method.

Comment: @Dbugger : By default, the POST method is used. Why do you intend to do ? You can download the demo for see more details.

Comment: Im doing more process to the file than simply upload, like compression and stuff...

Comment: Ok. You can do more process in the server side php script : upload.php. Download the pluploader and check out it (examples/upload.php)

Comment: I've seen this method also uses a SWF file, which automatically fails for me, since it doesnt work well on Linux :(

Comment: This method can use falsh, html5, silverlight or other. You must configure the runtime to use with the runtimes param. See example code at the bottom of this page : http://www.plupload.com/example_all_runtimes.php

Comment: Ok, this looks promising, but I still can't understand how this works. There's no "submit" button, so there's no reload of page so I can't access any $_POST variable. What should I do?

Comment: For use a form with a submit button, you can see the demo file like plupload/examples/custom.html or plupload/examples/custom.html. Then, you can how to use the $_POST variable in the demo file : plupload/examples/dump.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AJAX, you could go with [this solution](http://encodable.com/filechucker/). And here are [a few using jQuery](http://www.bitrepository.com/uploading-files-with-progress-bar.html).

Comment: I want to do some processing with the file and I also would want something that wouldnt be too intrusive with the site design. All these plugins are huge boxes... What I was hoping for was some technique to do it myself. and many of those links are using SWFUpload